# How to design up arrow in button in xml

Tags: android, button

I want to design like the image given below: when I select any button it should appear up arrow with background color on selected button.

[image]

Comment: Create an Image for it and set it as button's background dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Use button selector for it like this. or follow this link http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/

**button_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed_yellow"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused_orange"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal_green" />
</selector>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/imageButtonSelector"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/new_button" />

</LinearLayout>
```